# Determine if Gossip Protocol is working with Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have an 6 node VM Apache Cassnadra 1.0.6 ring installed at a customer.  We use HA Proxy in a cloud provider.  We had originally provided the complete setup and then the customers IT went in there to make it better.  Now we continue to have issues of which we are being blamed and we must determine the cause.

I see on one specific node, we continue to have a high hinted hand-off queue.  I also see a node that has very little data.

I suspect the nodes are not communicating around the ring.  Is there a command or some other tool or method I can use to see if gossip messages are going around the ring as they should?

More general, what are the best methods/tools for determining the health/config of the network of a Cassandra ring.  I want to make sure that all the nodes are able to communicate with each other via gossip and data is being replicated.

Answer (score 2):

As we all know Gossip protocol is responsible for peer to peer communication, so basically if we track the rpc port i.e 9160 (default), then we can get some related information

```
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47166      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47164      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:47162      XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       ESTABLISHED 1334/python2.7   off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47163      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:47164      XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       ESTABLISHED 1334/python2.7   off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47167      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47165      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:47166      XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       ESTABLISHED 1334/python2.7   off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47162      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp        0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       XXX.XX.XX.XX:47168      ESTABLISHED 21990/java       keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:47167      XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       ESTABLISHED 2215/java        keepalive (5554.50/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 XXX.XX.XX.XX:47168      XXX.XX.XX.XX:9160       ESTABLISHED 1189/java        off (0.00/0/0)
```

From this information, we can easily determine, yes Gossip is still working.